# Are “Cyclic homsets” similar to cyclic groups?

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, definition

A **cyclic group** $G$ is a group such that there is an element $f$, such that for every $g\in G$, we have that $g=f^z$ for some $z\in \mathbb Z$.

Let $C$ be a category with objects $X,Y$. We can call the homset $\text{Hom}(X,Y)$ a “**cyclic homset**” if there is an element $f:X\to X$ and $h:X\to Y$, such that for every element $g\in \text{Hom}(X,Y)$, we have that $g=h\circ f^n$ for some $n\in \mathbb N$.

Does this concept exist? Do cyclic homsets have similar properties as cyclic groups or cyclic monoids?

Comment: Do you mean $g=h\circ f^n$? The composition $f\circ h^n$ is not quite well defined. (And with the former definition, every homset is cyclic by taking $f=\text{id}_X$)

Comment: @RafayAshary yes, thank you, typo.

Comment: Since cyclic groups would not in general satisfy this (in the obvious translation), it looks more like cyclic semigroups or monoids.

Comment: If G is a group considered as a category, ie. the object is only G, and the morphisms are left (or right) multiplication by elements of G, then G has cyclic hom-sets all the time.